# How to create a new data frame with the mean of 2 columns grouped by another variable using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I have the following data frame (called `df1`) in `R`.

```
dept     salary1     salary2
 A         1000        1500
 A         3000        2500
 B         1500        1300
 C         4000        4200
 C         2900        1800
 C         1300         900
 D         6000        5200
 D         8000        8400
```

I want to convert this data frame into the following (called `df2`):

```
dept     MeanSalary1    MeanSalary2
 A         2000           2000
 B         1500           1300
 C         2733           2300
 D         7000           6800
```

How can I do this using `dplyr`?

Comment: `df1 %>% group_by(dept) %>% summarise(MeanSalary1 = mean(salary1), MeanSalary2 = mean(salary2))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `summarise_all` to calculate the mean for all the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(dept) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(Mean = mean(.))) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   dept  salary1_Mean salary2_Mean
#   <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 A            2000          2000
# 2 B            1500          1300
# 3 C            2733.         2300
# 4 D            7000          6800
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "dept     salary1     salary2
 A         1000        1500
 A         3000        2500
 B         1500        1300
 C         4000        4200
 C         2900        1800
 C         1300         900
 D         6000        5200
 D         8000        8400",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```